# Seeking world map (epsg 3857) tile boundaries in shapefile?

Tags: data, tiles, mapbox

I am working on manipulating data and I need a shapefile of world map tile in each zoom level.

It could be better if it is in polygon but line is also fine.
I tried to find the file using as many keywords as I can. Yet, I was not able to find anything.

It has to be as same as mapbox tile boundaries.
For those who have this data, please do share for the GIS users.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/mapbox/mercantile to generate these tiles:

```
$ export zoom=0
$ echo "[-180, -85, 180, 85]" | mercantile tiles $zoom | mercantile shapes > tiles_$zoom.geojson
```